# palatino-Bold, palatino-Roman, palatino-Italic belongs to which package?

Tags: fonts, mathpazo

palatino-Bold, palatino-Roman, palatino-Italic belongs to which package? The `palatino` and `mathpazo` are not well enouugh for me, is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not clear what you're asking: with `\usepackage{mathpazo}` you can say `\textbf{text}` to get "text" typeset with Palatino Bold.

Comment: thank you for your reply,i know what you have written means,but when i use the adobe acrobat pro to analysis the article it shows that the typefont is URWPalatinoL-Bold,not Palatino-Bold,that is what i am worried about

Comment: URWPalatino is the Palatino clone shipped with TeX Live and MiKTeX. There are licensing problem in using the Adobe fonts.

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of packages which provide Palatino (or very similar):

- [`tgpagella`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgpagella/) provides TeX Gyre Pagella – an improved version of URW Palladio.
- [`mathpazo`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/palatino/) provides URW Palladio – a Palatino clone.
- [`pxfonts`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/pxfonts/) also provides URW Palladio, but slightly diffent.

A quick comparison:

[image: tgpagella]
[image: mathpazo]
[image: pxfonts]

(images courtesy of The LaTeX Font Catalogue)

You can also use the Palatino font installed on your computer with `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino}
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog
\end{document}
```

[image: fontspec]

Comment: thank you very much for your reply,i know what you have written means,but when i use the adobe acrobat pro to analysis the article it shows that the typefont is URWPalatinoL-Bold,not the wanted typefont--- Palatino-Bold,that is what i am worrying about

Answer (score 0):

You can use these packages in the preamble region. These fonts belong to TeXGyrePagella, a modified version of the Palatino font.

```latex
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
```

You can find more information at [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newpx).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is a very poor answer as it lacks explanations. Please edit your answer to elaborate on your suggestion.